# do i need to set guards for passport routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am confused after a lot of reading, I think that I have understood less than before!

I have my passport configured on Laravel 8:

```php
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'users',
],
```

So I am serving via these routes: `login`, `logout` and `registration`.

```php
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
```

And the `AuthController` provides the methods and almost works!

My questions are:

- If I add a guard to `logout` this will not work. So is it unnecessary or am I with wrong logic? Or is it correct as I've written?
- Do I need to manage `refresh tokens`? And if yes, should the route be guarded? Or what have I to do when the token expires?

I have tried to add a method:

```php
public function refresh() {
    return $this->createNewToken(auth()->refresh());
}
```

But this gives me back this error:

> BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::refresh
> does not exist. in file
> /home/natty/workspace/sportIndexBackEnd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php
> on line 103